# Android Development: Passing "menu" class to other activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-intent

I have a menu.java and in this file I have lines of codes to allow the user to press the menu button and "MENU1" and "MENU2" will appear on their android phone. However, I have multiple java classes, and each java classes is its own activity. What would I need to do to have this menu class function in each activity without putting every line of code in the menu.java into each other .java

This is my Menu.java

public class Menu extends Activity {

```
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu){
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
            MenuInflater a = getMenuInflater();
            a.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
            return true;
        }
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

            switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.MENU1:
                startActivity(new Intent("com.helloworld.test.MENU1"));
                return true;
            case R.id.MENU2:
                startActivity(new Intent("com.helloworld.test.MENU2"));
                return true;

            }
            return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: just extend this menu instead of Activity in all your activities.

Comment: well I already have public class Menu extends Activity. so if my other classes will have public class OtherActivity extends Menu, because my menu will already have this activity in it correct?

Comment: yeah and suppose if you want to use another menu then simply you will have to override the menu methods in your activity,just simply extends the menu class instead of Activity class and check yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a base activity that all your other activities extend:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu){
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater a = getMenuInflater();
        a.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

        switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.MENU1:
            startActivity(new Intent("com.helloworld.test.MENU1"));
            return true;
        case R.id.MENU2:
            startActivity(new Intent("com.helloworld.test.MENU2"));
            return true;

        }
        return false;
    }
}
```